# MSSQL - Extract value from XML attribute regardless of postion

Tags: sql-server, xml

So I know how to extract a value from XML if you specify the path.
This is the query I have so far:

```
with cte as
(
    select cast(ds.SelectBuilderXML as xml) as xml from [DataSelect] ds
)


select 
cte.xml.value('(/SqlBuilderSelect/Columns/Expression/Term/Value/Logical/@UniqueIdent)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as LogicalCol
from cte
```

What I would like to do is extract the UniqueIdent attribute text, regardless of the path within the XML.UniqueIdent with the XML below you can see the UniqueIdent attribute is found in multiple locations:

```
<SqlBuilderSelect MasterDimension="6">
  <Columns ColumnAlias="test">
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <BaseType>Constant</BaseType>
    <Expressions>
      <Term>
        <Value Type="Constant">
          <Constant Name="test" />
        </Value>
      </Term>
    </Expressions>
  </Columns>
  <Columns ColumnAlias="test">
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <BaseType>Logical</BaseType>
    <Expressions>
      <Term>
        <Value Type="Logical">
          <Logical UniqueIdent="4aa2c9a7-b745-4929-8ceb-f68fddc80ce1" />
        </Value>
      </Term>
    </Expressions>
  </Columns>
  <Where JoinType="AND">
    <Children>
      <Where JoinType="AND" whereID="ddddbb62-88a3-46a6-b2db-7ee51dd3699c">
        <Condition Operator="Equal" UniqueID="00ec987e-5d60-4d0d-b91b-1fb090725cb7">
          <FirstTerm ColumnBaseType="Logical">
            <Visible>true</Visible>
            <BaseType>Logical</BaseType>
            <Expressions>
              <Term>
                <Value Type="Logical">
                  <Logical UniqueIdent="19ae3aca-b1d6-4eea-b78c-86e8d62ba960" />
                </Value>
              </Term>
            </Expressions>
          </FirstTerm>
        </Condition>
      </Where>
    </Children>
  </Where>
  <JoinOverrides>
    <JoinOverride FromPath="" ToPath="test" JoinType="Left" subselectjoin="false" />
  </JoinOverrides>
  <ParametersDefinitions>
    <Parameter Name="EndDate" />
  </ParametersDefinitions>
  <SystemShortCode>fd015bf9-aed2-41e4-8923-a256934ae344</SystemShortCode>
</SqlBuilderSelect>
```

So the results that would be returned are, based on the XML above:

```
UniqueIdent
------------------------------------    
4aa2c9a7-b745-4929-8ceb-f68fddc80ce1
19ae3aca-b1d6-4eea-b78c-86e8d62ba960
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to pick the XML nodes you want to base your output on. Here we want one output row per `<Logical>` element, per table row.

The XPath expression `//Logical` would select all these elements from a document, and the T-SQL function `.nodes()` applies XPath to an XML column. With your sample XML, this will produce two elements.

That means we get multiple output rows per input row, so we need to "join" the function result to the table/CTE, and joining function results is done with `cross apply`.

Finally, we want to select the `.value()` if the `UniqueIdent` attribute from each of the elements.

```sql
with cte as
(
    select cast(ds.SelectBuilderXML as xml) as xml from [DataSelect] ds
)
select T.Logical.value('@UniqueIdent', 'varchar(36)') as UniqueIdent
from cte cross apply cte.xml.nodes('//Logical') as T(Logical)
```